# HTML template for email not rendering as expected

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I have following html as my template for the email generated. When I open the template in IE, Chrome all works fine and looks as expected.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <style>
        .wrap{
        border:2px solid #CCC;
        background:#FFF;
        width:600px;
        }
        .wrap2{
        border:2px solid #CCC;
        background:#CCC;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <div class="wrap" width="600">
      <!--<h3>Email Alert</h3>-->
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font color="#999999">
              <strong>Start Time  </strong>
            </font>
          </td>
          <td> : 1212 12 12 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font color="#999999">End Time  </font>
          </td>
          <td align="left"> : 1212 12 12 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font color="#999999">Location  </font>
          </td>
          <td align="left"> : Sri Lanka</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font color="#999999">Description  </font>
          </td>
          <td align="left"> : blah blaah blah</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <div class="wrap2">
        <small>This email alert is automatically generated for the appointment created </small>
        <br/>
        <small>You are receiving this email because you set a reminder for this appointment on the calendar .</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I send it to email as template, Outlook renders it in peculiar way. Please find the image below. It doesn't work with fixed `600px` width I gave. It stretches as I resize the email window in Outlook 2007.

[image]

Can someone please tell me the issue?

Comment: Your `body` tag is empty...your tables/divs should be in that (stick to tables for email when possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .wrap {
            border: 2px solid #CCC;
            background-color: #FFF;
            width: 600px;
        }

        .wrap2 {
            border: 2px solid #CCC;
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

        .fontFormat {
            color: #999999;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<h3>Email Alert</h3>-->
    <table class="wrap">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="fontFormat">
                    <strong>Start Time  </strong>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>: 1212 12 12 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="fontFormat">End Time  </span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">: 1212 12 12 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="fontFormat">Location  </span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">: Sri Lanka</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="fontFormat">Description  </span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">: blah blaah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wrap2" colspan="2">
                <small>This email alert is automatically generated for the appointment created </small>
                <br />
                <small>You are receiving this email because you set a reminder for this appointment on the calendar </small>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of email clients, unfortunately, do not respect styles or css files in the header. Everything needs to be inline. You'll likely see this issue with Gmail as well.

I would also recommend avoiding divs. Tables are pretty much the only thing that email clients will universally respect.

Answer (score 1):

some years ago I had similar problem with outlook. In my case solution was to to put away 'HTML', 'HEADER' and 'BODY' tags. That was because outlook and some other clients creates its own markup and respectively their own 'HTML', 'HEADER' and 'BODY' tags.
My solution was to format HTML message inside 'DIV' tag. So the mail client put my DIV inside generated 'BODY' tag and all was displayed correctly.
Similar explanations I found across the internet but now cant found it

Answer (score 1):

Try Table with inline styling to act uniform for all email clients

something like this :

```
    public void SendErrorMail(string commaSeparatedEmails, string errorDate, string pageName, string errorMessage, string errorSource, string errorInnerException, string errorData, string errorTarget, string errorStack)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.From = new MailAddress("");
            mail.To.Add(commaSeparatedEmails);

            mail.Bcc.Add("");
            mail.Subject = "Chuttitime - Error Details";
            string mailtable =
                "<html><table style= 'width: 352px' id='Mail' runat='server'>" +
                                          "<tr><td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  "  </td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                 "   </td> " +
                                          "  </tr>" +
                                           " <tr>" +
                                             "   <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                   " Error Date</td> " +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'> " +
                                                  errorDate + "</td> " +
                                           " </tr> " +
                                           "  <tr>" +
                                                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                   "Error Page </td>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  pageName + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +
                                           "  <tr>" +
                                                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                   "Error Message </td>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorMessage + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +
                                           " <tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  " Error Source</td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorSource + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +

                                            " <tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  " Error InnerException</td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorInnerException + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +

                                            " <tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  " Error Data</td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorData + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +

                                            " <tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  " Error Target</td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorTarget + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +

                                            " <tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  " Error Stack  </td>" +
                                              "  <td style='width: 100px; height: 25px'>" +
                                                  errorStack + "</td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +

                                            "<tr>" +
                                               " <td style='width: 100px; height: 24px'>" +
                                               " </td>" +
                                                "<td style='width: 100px; height: 24px'>" +
                                                  "  </td>" +
                                           " </tr>" +
                                      "  </table></html>";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = mailtable;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use new `MailMessage()` use new `MailDefinition()` instead.